# bootstrap table export for letters ć, č, ž does not work

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap table export (Extension for bootstrap table. bootstrap-table-export.js plugin is used) and available formats are JSON, XML, ONG, CSV, SQL, MS-WORD, MS-EXCEL, PDF. 
If I have letters like ć ,č ,ž, š  table export does not work. If I don't have these letters in table it works great. I was wondering can table export work for letters ć č š  and if yes what needs to be changed.

Did anyone face this kind of a problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is boostrap table export?

Comment: Extension for bootstrap table. bootstrap-table-export.js plugin is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution on github. I am posting an answer in case someone needs help later:

Plugin base64 needs to be updated.

Solution is on https://gist.github.com/wenzhixin/09e218c884f4f380b68a.