# Jquery table export plugin - encoding specific letters in pdf

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, pdf, encoding

I started to use the jquery plugin called "tableExport.jquery.plugin" from this [github site](https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin)
on my jsp page. But I have a problem with it because if I have letters like **ż, ł, ę, ć, ś, ą**, table export **does not work only for PDF file.** Only letter **ó** display correctly in pdf. When I export to **doc, csv, xls and others** the letter display correctly.

I also tried this: [bootstrap table export for letters ć, č, ž does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265074/bootstrap-table-export-for-letters-%C4%87-%C4%8D-%C5%BE-does-not-work) but it did not help.

On the page I have encoding set in this way:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

What may be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin uses jsPDF as PDF producer. It is a known issue of that plugin, that it has no real unicode support. Only a few unicode characters (as german umlauts) are supported.